# Help with Troubleshooting Zero Connections to a New Monero Node

Tags: monerod

New to setting up my own Monero node. Hoping to join the faithful :)

I have QNAP NAS which I currently have a successful Docker Bitcoin node running on. I am looking to do the same with Monero. The QNAP NAS has a Container Management Tool built in called ContainerStation. I have used the Docker image here https://hub.docker.com/r/kannix/monero-full-node posted by Kannix. Everything installs and starts up fine, it is set to run on ports 18080 and 18081 which I believe are standard from my reading. The blockchain is syncing fine but I when I run the status command I show zero connections... even though I am obviously connected to something, otherwise I couldn't be getting synchronized, at least that's my understanding. The results of the status command are below:

```
$ ./monerod status                                                                                                                                              
2021-02-21 06:29:29.865 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.9-release)                                                                                             
Error: Problem fetching info-- rpc_request:                                                                                                                     
Height: 1328116/2301498 (57.7%) on mainnet, mining info unavailable, net hash 76.54 MH/s, v5, 0(out)+0(in) connections
```

I have created the necessary port forwarding rules on my firewall. I have checked that the ports are forwarding correctly with https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/. Both 18080 and 18081 show as open.

As I mentioned at the beginning of the post, I have a Docker Bitcoin node running successfully with a very similar setup, I used the Docker image here https://hub.docker.com/r/kylemanna/bitcoind posted by Kylemanna. I haven't had any issues with the Bitcoin node, connections are good. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction, I would like to participate in helping make the dream work :) Any thoughts on what could be causing the lack of connections reported when running this status command?

Comment: Are 18081 and 18080 ports opened? Does your firewall allows inbound and outbound connections?